# Why the scent of mouth gets dirty after not eating for a long time?

Tags: human-biology, physiology

After a long time of hard workout,not eating and nervousness makes your taste and scent of mouth very uncomfortable and bad why this happens and is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a build up of ketone bodies in your blood which lowers the pH of your body and can cause bad breath. Ketone bodies are a response of your body breaking down fatty acids for energy instead of glucose when in a low food intake (fasting) state. This is also true for morning breath since your body has been in a fasting state.
The way to prevent this is to eat the proper amount of calories needed for your body to function normally.